# How can I refresh the values of variables every second in C# with the Scripthookvdotnet for GTA5

Tags: c#

So I've got 5 variables

`string name, int health, bool alarm, float someFloat, int dirt`

In a void(`void VehicleInfo()`)

How can I make those variables refresh every second? I'm searching for an answer for days and I can't find anything..

`void VehicleInfo(){`

```
        string name = Game.Player.Character.CurrentVehicle.DisplayName;
        int health = Game.Player.Character.CurrentVehicle.Health;
        bool alarm = Game.Player.Character.CurrentVehicle.AlarmActive;
        float someFloat = Game.Player.Character.CurrentVehicle.DirtLevel;
        int dirt = (int)Math.Round(someFloat);

       

        UIMenu VehInfo = modMenuPool.AddSubMenu(mainMenu, "Vehicle Info");

        UIMenuItem Name;
        UIMenuItem Health;
        UIMenuItem Dirt;
        UIMenuItem Alarm;

        Name = new UIMenuItem("Vehicle Name: " + name);
        VehInfo.AddItem(Name);
        
        Health = new UIMenuItem("Vehicle Health: " + health);
        VehInfo.AddItem(Health);

        Dirt = new UIMenuItem("Vehicle Dirt Level: " + dirt);
        VehInfo.AddItem(Dirt);

        Alarm = new UIMenuItem("Does This Vehicle Have Alarm: " + alarm);
        VehInfo.AddItem(Alarm);`
```

I need to refresh the variables from Game values

Comment: What do you mean refresh? From a database/datasource? From user input? from where?

Comment: This is not enough information to give you a suggestion much less solution. Please provide a minimal reproducible example that you are working with

Comment: I've edited the question, if you need more details, comment them

Comment: What sort of app is this? WinForms? WPF? Unity? Something else?

Comment: A mod for GTA V using NativeUI

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the examples over at [github](https://github.com/crosire/scripthookvdotnet/blob/f98d8b87d363371910b9ff6228e7e4f0f917155f/examples/IndicatorControl.cs)

You can inhertit from `Script`

In the constructor you then specify an interval (every X milliseconds) and an event handler for when the tick happens.

```
public YourClass()
{
   Tick += OnTick;
   Interval = 1000; // Every Second 
}

// This method is called every 1 second, based on the Interval
private void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string name = Game.Player.Character.CurrentVehicle.DisplayName;
   int health = Game.Player.Character.CurrentVehicle.Health;
   bool alarm = Game.Player.Character.CurrentVehicle.AlarmActive;
   float someFloat = Game.Player.Character.CurrentVehicle.DirtLevel;
   int dirt = (int)Math.Round(someFloat);
   // The rest of your code
}
```

See the source code of the [script](https://github.com/crosire/scripthookvdotnet/blob/f98d8b87d363371910b9ff6228e7e4f0f917155f/source/core/Script.cs) class to get a better understanding.

Comment: Dosen't work because it adds a submenu every second..

Comment: If you move the creation of `modMenuPool.AddSubMenu(mainMenu, "Vehicle Info");` to somewhere else like constructor or when a button is pressed and store it in field instead of a variable so you can access it in OnTick you may get there.